# Saving a buffer in Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to find a solution that will let me stream in-memory created zip to Google Cloud Bucket (I'm using Firebase, but seems like it's beyond it so I need to handle it through GCB).

I have nailed down file creation part (code below) and when it's working locally on my machine it saves it in the main folder where server files reside. So far so good.

Now I found [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#streaming_uploads) that lets stream transfers, but not sure how to connect them. Should it be after zip is created? Instead? Any suggestions are welcome!

```
const express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var archiver = require('archiver')
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("../servicekey.json")
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "myName.appspot.com"
})
var bucket = admin.storage().bucket()

const {
  convertCSVtoJSON,
  generateDocuments,
  generateDocx,
  isCorrectTemplateFileType
} = require('./generateServices')

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if(!isCorrectTemplateFileType(req.files.template))
      return res.status(403).send({
        message: 'Wrong file type. Please provide .docx file.'
      })

    const template = req.files.template.data
    const data = await convertCSVtoJSON(req.files.data1)

    let zip = archiver('zip')
    
    zip.on('warning', function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });

    zip.on('error', function(err) {
      res.status(500).send({error: err.message})
    });

    zip.on('entry', function(ars) {
      // console.log(ars)
    });

    zip.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Archive wrote %d bytes', zip.pointer())
    });

    // res.attachment('archive-name.zip')
  
    // zip.pipe(output)
    // zip.pipe(res)
    
    data.forEach((docData, index) => {
      let buff = generateDocx(template, docData, 'title')
      zip.append(buff, { name: `${index}.docx` })
    })

    zip.finalize()

    console.log(zip)
    const file = bucket.file("pliki.zip") // nazwa do zmiany
    file.save(zip, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("cool");
      } else {
        console.log("error " + err);
      }
    });

    res.sendStatus(201)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.send(error)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Why do you want to stream the buffer? Is the file too large to stay in memory?

Comment: One word of caution: If you stream an upload there's no way to provide a checksum (since checksums are part of the headers sent at the start of the upload). That means you could have undetected data corruption. Can you instead buffer locally (to RAM or disk) and then upload the complete file?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Because I'm not really sure how much memory Firebase offers. And what if someone has a template that has 1MB and need 5000 of them filled. Then it's ~5GB. But yeah, there is also a risk there would be error and already some content was streamed so I should probably do it in memory and put some limits.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I'm planning to use Firebase Functions for that - from what I read I can save in memory, but it will be available until the end of function processing.

Comment: You can have up to 2Gb of memory with Firebase function, (like Cloud Functions). if you need more, you can use Cloud Run with up to 8Gb of memory, and still serverless. And I confirm, stream write doesn't check the CRC and with ZIP, only 1 bit in error and your zip is unreadable! Not a good idea

Comment: Actually, if you go to the GCP project's Cloud Console associated with the project where your Firebase Functions reside you can change the memory allocation value up to 4GB as stated on the Max function memory value [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#resource_limits). Take into consideration that everything written to the [\tmp folder](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) is counted to your RAM usage, and if not monitoring usage appropriately you could easily reach OOM error messages if the files take the whole RAM space.

Comment: Interesting, I will definitely dive into that more - seems like I omitted some important knowledge in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I made some changes. File is getting uploaded, but it's empty when I check it - not sure what I'm not doing right. I suppose I should use `createWriteStream()`, but is there any other way to upload created zip?